# How can I compare today's date with another date from the database?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is what I have so far

```
<div v-for="product in products">

<div v-if="Date.now() > {{ product.expiry_date }}">Expired</div>
<div v-if="Date.now() < {{ product.expiry_date }}">Valid</div>

</div>
```

```
var app = new Vue({
    'el': '#myapp',
    data: {
        products: "",
    },
    methods: {
        allRecords: function(){
            axios.get('ajaxfile.php')
                .then(function (response) {
                    app.products = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },

    }
})
```

I want to print `Expired` or `Valid` by comparing dates in my database and the date today. I am not sure if the if condition's format i.e. this part `{{ product.expiry_date }}` is correct. Is there another way for representing date data from a database in an if condition? I get no output with that format, would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :::

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>How to get current date time in vue js? - ItSolutionStuff.com</title>
        </head>
        <body>
           
        <div id="app">
        <ul id="example-1">
          <li v-for="item in items">
            {{item.name}} - 
            <span  v-if="Date.now() > new Date(item.date)">Expired</span>
            <span v-if="Date.now() < new Date(item.date)">Valid</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
          
        </body>
          
        <script type="text/javascript">
         new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: { 
                 items: [
          { date: '2006-12-30', name: 'AAA' }, 
          { date: '2020-12-30', name: 'BBB' }
        ]
              }
         });
            
        </script>
        </html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! How could I represent the date that's fetched from the database in that if condition? All I know is that it is represented otherwise like ```{{product.expiry_date}}```.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function or a flag which compares today's date and expiry date.

```
function isExpired(expiryDate) {
  return Date.now() < (new Date(expiryDate).getTime());
}
```

then call this function from your template.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! How could I represent the date that's fetched from the database in that if condition? All I know is that it is represented otherwise like ```{{product.expiry_date}}```.

Comment: You could write v-if="!isExpired(product.expiry_date)"

Answer (score 0):

Use `getTime` method to find difference in javascript.

This is the sample code to apply where you want.

```js
var date1 = new Date(); 
var date2 = new Date(2019 - 08 - 03); 
if (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) 
    document.write("date is valid"); 
else if (date1.getTime() > date2.getTime()) 
    document.write("date is expired"); 
else
    document.write("date is valid today only");
```

Update Answer

```js
var date1 = new Date(); 
var date2 = new Date(2019 - 08 - 03); 
var result = (date1.getTime() >= date2.getTime())?'expired':'valid';
console.log( result );
```

Use only `{{ (date1.getTime() >= date2.getTime())?'expired':'valid' }}` in your condition.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! How could I represent the date that's fetched from the database in that if condition? All I know is that it is represented otherwise like ```{{product.expiry_date}}```.

Comment: Could I do something like : ```<div v-if="Date.now() < new Date({{ product.expiry_date }})">Valid</div>``` ?